# coefplot in R; change CI line colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, coefplot

Hi I'm using coefplot function in r to plot out the coefficients from a generalized linear model. I would like to change the colour of the 95% CI lines to be different from the 50% CI lines. The colour parameters defaults the same colour for both the 95% and 50% CI lines.

```
coeff<-coefplot(model1,pointSize=5,color="black",fillColor="grey",lwdOuter = 1.2,lwdInner=2)

coeff + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme (axis.title.y  = element_text(size=16)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=16)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name="",labels=c("NDAA","GAP","SS","PS","LL")) +
  theme (axis.text.x  = element_text(size=16)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=16)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Regression Estimate") +
  labs(title = "") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably create your own version of a coefficient plot that meets your needs without too much trouble. Here's a `ggplot2` example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a model to plot
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + carb, data=mtcars)
coefs = as.data.frame(summary(m1)$coefficients[-1,1:2])
names(coefs)[2] = "se" 
coefs$vars = rownames(coefs)

ggplot(coefs, aes(vars, Estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2, lwd=1, colour="grey50") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Estimate - 1.96*se, ymax=Estimate + 1.96*se), 
                lwd=1, colour="red", width=0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Estimate - se, ymax=Estimate + se), 
                lwd=2.5, colour="blue", width=0) +
  geom_point(size=4, pch=21, fill="yellow") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Another point is to use the `coefplot` output and not your own coefficients. `mm <- coefplot(model1,plot=FALSE)` then you use `"HighInner", "LowInner", "HighOuter`..` variables. Maybe you can keep this to the OP as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily change the color here. 
Unfortunately the package don't give access to set colors here.

1. Either  you change the grobs colors using `grid` package or `gTable`. This is the dirty solution. It assume you know a little bit how to navigate in the ggplot tree objects ( gpath)
2. Or you add a new color parameter to [buildPlotting.lm](https://github.com/jaredlander/coefplot/blob/9335c1ad3bf32cc8b7cb41d62ed51e125911e838/inst/deprecated/utilities.r) . You should recompile the package.

Comment: Thanks agstudy. Was beginning to suspect something as you mentioned but wanted to confirm first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You can solve it within `coefplot` if you alter the individual `ggplot2` layers.

```
coef <- coefplot(model = model1
     , color = "blue"
     ) +
      theme_bw() 
coef$layers[[2]] <- geom_errorbarh(stat="identity", position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE
                                    , color = "yellow"
                                    , size = 1
                                    , mapping = aes(xmin = LowOuter, xmax = HighOuter
                                                    , height = 0, linetype = Model 
                                    ))
coef$layers[[3]] <- geom_errorbarh(stat="identity", position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE
                                    , color = "red"
                                    , size = 2
                                    , mapping = aes(xmin = LowInner, xmax = HighInner
                                          , height = 0, linetype = Model
                                          ))
coef
```

[coefplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkJ22.png)